# How can I change the following code to not use eval?

Tags: javascript, json, eval

```
var settings = {};

$(".js-gen-settings").each(function(){
    var date;

    if (($(this).attr("type") === "checkbox") || ($(this).attr("type") === "radio")){//if its a checkbox
        eval("settings."+this.name+" = "+$(this).is(":checked"));
    }else{
        date = $(this).val();
        if (date == ""){
            eval("settings." + this.name + " = null");
        }else{
            eval("settings." + this.name + " = '" + date + "'");
        }
    }
});
```

a `JSON.stringify` version of `settings` will be sent to the server using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I've re-factored your code:

```
$( '.js-gen-settings' ).each(function () { 

    if ( $( this ).is( ':checkbox, :radio' ) ) {
        settings[ this.name ] = this.checked;
    } else {
        settings[ this.name ] = this.value ? this.value : null;
    }

});
```

Comment: I also need to make sure the value is not an empty string, just checking `this.value ?` will work or do I need to do: `(this.value && (this.value !== "")) ?`

Comment: @gandazgul Just `this.value ?` will work fine since `this.value` always returns a String value, and an empty string is the only String value which is falsy (which coerces to `false`).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I've changed my code, yours is more elegant, short and sweet.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to modify a property of an object dynamically, you just put the name in `[`brackets`]`.

```
settings[this.name] = null

settings[this.name] = date;

settings[this.name] = $(this).is(":checked");
```

Comment: @gandazgul: Glad to have been of help. :) If you think this answer has solved your problem, you may chose to select it as the "accepted answer" for this question by clicking the grey checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
eval("settings." + this.name + " = null")
```

to

```
settings[this.name] = null;
```

I'm sure you can figure out the rest :)